# Confusion around svelte Reactivity tutorial

Tags: svelte

The [Svelte tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/updating-arrays-and-objects) mentions the following in the « Reactivity > Updating arrays and object » chapter:

[image]

The documentation mentions updating references to `obj.foo.bar` but the `foo` variable is a separate copy of `obj.foo`. So I can't see how doing `obj=obj` would update reference to `obj.foo.bar`, as `bar` is declared as an object property for `foo`, not for `obj.foo`.

Can someone translate what is meant here? There is probably a bug to file at least for clarifying things but I'd need to understand what's meant here first.

Comment: foo is not a separate copy of "obj.foo", it is actually a reference to it, when you assign an object to a variable you are just assigning it's reference (the 2 variables will share the same object). to create a copy, you need to either manually create a new object and append the keys or JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this REPL that will help with understanding why the reassignment is necessary. https://svelte.dev/repl/e37be0fa87844cc18f1064b711d427ad?version=3.29.7